# How to get a range of elements from an array in Redisjson?

Tags: redis, redisjson

I have a simple array as such :

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and I wish to get a range for example from index 2 to index 4.
I can get the last element of the array by :

```
json.get key .[-1]
```

However I cannot find anyway to return a specific results without trimming the array.

Is there anyway I can get a range of elements from a Redis json array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is :

```
await Client.json.get("key" , {path : '$.[1:3]'})
```

which gets index 1 to 3.